# Calling `logging` interferes other modules

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have the following `a.py` which calls `b.py`

`b.py`

```py
import logging
  
logging.info('11111 in b')     

def do():                      
    logging.info('2222222 in b')
```

`a.py`

```py
import logging
import sys
import b

logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
logging.info('11111111 in a')
b.do()
```

When I execute `a.py`, nothing gets logged to `stdout`, but when I comment out `logging.info('11111 in b')` from `b.py` as below:

`b.p`y

```py
import logging
  
# logging.info('11111 in b')     

def do():                      
    logging.info('2222222 in b')
```

I can see log output:

```
INFO:root:11111111 in a
INFO:root:2222222 in b
```

So obviously there is something to do with that commented out line, but I would have thought the `basicConfig()` would set something straight after importing `b` module but it's not.

Could someone please explain what's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import statement `import b` has triggered a logging event *before* the logging system gets configured. When events are logged with an unconfigured logging system, it gets *auto-configured* with a default configuration: a stream handler at level WARNING on stderr.

The subsequent `basicConfig` call does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured. Hence the INFO level events are filtered out, because the root logger is configured with a handler at the higher threshold of WARNING.

The proper solution is ensure events are not logged before the logging system has been configured. Usually this means avoiding log events or doing any work at the global (module level) scope.

However, [since Python 3.8](https://bugs.python.org/issue33897) there is a workaround to force reconfiguring the logging system:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO, force=True)
```

In older Python versions, you could clear the root logging handlers manually:

```
del logging.getLogger().handlers[:]
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: oh thanks, so it just ignores subsequent `basicConfig()` calls if `force` param is not set to `True`?

Comment: I tried using `force=True` but it's not working

Comment: It works with the example as shown in your question.  If it's not working for you, there must be something else not shown.

Comment: You sure about that, did you comment out the `logging.info('11111 in b)` in `b.py`?

Comment: It might depend on your Python version. I get ValueError: Unrecognised argument(s): force

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.0

Comment: Yes, I'm sure about that.  Here's a live example on repl.it  https://repl.it/join/bvuafmwh-wimglenn

Comment: I am also getting `ValueError: Unrecognised argument(s): force`

Comment: Ah, you're on older version of Python.  [force reconfigure is a new feature in 3.8](https://bugs.python.org/issue33897).

Comment: ah I see, gotcha

Comment: Added a workaround for older Python versions.  But I emphasize that the correct solution is not to log events before the logging system has been configured.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it has something to do with how the output is being configured. I don't think setting it in a.py will set it for both files, kind of like how you have to import logging in both files or else get an error.

If you add the basicConfig line to b.py, then you can keep your `logging.info('11111 in b')` and see it printed.

Comment: The question is, why running `basicConfig()` in `a.py` didn't set things right afterwards

Comment: The Python docs: "The call to basicConfig() should come before any calls to debug(), info() etc. As it’s intended as a one-off simple configuration facility, only the first call will actually do anything: subsequent calls are effectively no-ops." https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html

Comment: OK, that makes sense